# method chaining in php class

Tags: php, class

I want to understand what is the difference between these chaining method

```
$obj->prop_a()->prob_b($y);
```

and

```
$obj->prop_a->prob_b($x);
```

how to define it and how it works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On

```
$obj->prop_a()->prob_b($y);
```

you access prop_a() as a **function**. It return (obviously) an object, which implements an prob_b()-function.

On

```
$obj->prop_a->prob_b($x);
```

you access prop_a as a **public property** which contains an object, which again implements an prob_b() function.

Answer (score 1):

One calls `prop_a` as a method, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
class A {
  public function prop_b($x) {
    return 4*$x;
  }
}

class B {
  public function prop_a() {
    $a = new A();
    return $a;
  }
}

class C {
  public $prop_a;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->prop_a = new A();
  }
}

$b = new B();
$c = new C();
$b->prop_a()->prob_b(5);
$c->prop_a->prop_b(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. However i've tested the code above, but it gives me this error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method A::prob_b() in D:\webdev\mvc\chain.php on line 24